# IR won't activate screen on 10.8.3 Mountain Lion Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac-mini, hibernate, apple-remote-desktop

I use my Mini for home theatre, but the IR won't active the screen.
Using Screen Sharing will activate the screen.
I see others have reported this issue with 10.8.2 that went away with 10.8.3. Alas 10.8.3 didn't cure this problem for me.

Originally I suspected it was due to sleep/hibernate, but this looks to be false as I can ssh into the Mini and use it fine. Also I ran the Plex home theatre app under "caffeinate", and it didn't help.

**Prior Research**: I have read many man pages, forums, articles (see refs at bottom). Tried many combinations of settings, but to no avail. I turn to StackExchange for guidance.

- My previous Mini running Snow Leopard worked just fine, but I don't wish to install Snow Leopard on my late model mini.
- I have tried the NVROM/PROM reset 4 times. Hasn't helped.

### My machine:

Mac mini - Late 2012 - Software  OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)

Reference Sites:
[Mac Mini won't wake after sleep with Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83655/mac-mini-wont-wake-after-sleep-with-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to get the display to wake up using your IR remote, but @wuc [provided a great workround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53802/waking-display-from-terminal-general-waking/72459) since you said you can ssh into the machine.

Step 1: SSH into your Mac.

Step 2: Run this command: `pmset schedule wake "01/01/2012 20:00:00"` (with a date of your choosing, of course).

[Here's a bit of background](http://www.iospirit.com/blog/article/157/Waking-the-sleeping-Lion-Remote-Buddy-1-18-1/) on the new "features" Apple added to Lion and Mountain Lion that make it harder to wake up your display.